# How to properly use sub query in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
......
.....

return myDb.myTable.rollgroup.findAll({

                attributes : ['ID','GROUPNAME'],
                where : {
                    id : {
                      $notIn: ? //// how to use subQuery here
                    }
                }


              }).then((getResult) => {

                  return getResult;

              })
.......
.......
```

My raw Query Like this:

select mg.ID,mg.GROUPNAME from mygroup mg where mg.ID not in (select egr.GROUPID from employeegrouprelation egr where egr.PID = ? )

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of sequelize.literal to wrap the subquery:

```
    ...

    id:{
        $notIn: sequelize.literal('(select egr.GROUPID from employeegrouprelation egr where egr.PID = ?)')
       }

    ...
```

Comment: The other way you could do it is to run the subquery first to return an array of groupid's and then chain the other query onto it using the result from the first. So something like `return model.findAll({attributes:['groupid'],where:{groupid: <value>}}).then((result)=>{next query here using result in the $notIn })`.  Whichever you prefer.